# how to edit link in content to point to article in joomla

Tags: joomla

Inside a joomla content, I need to place a link that points to another article within the same joomla site. How can I do this?
Note that is should work even if I change my joomla-based site name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest tool to use is Linkr - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/structure-a-navigation/content-links/4010

It makes it really easy to link to articles, sections etc.

Answer (score 0):

No problem. Just make it a relative link like

```
<a href="article1">my link to article1</a>
```

where "article1" is the name of the menu position that points to your target article. Assuming that you have SEO urls and mod_rewrite enabled this should be enough.

If you enabled SEO urls but don't have mod_rewrite then you need to change the href from "article1" to "index.php/article1".

```
<a href="index.php/article1">my link to article1</a>
```

Lastly, if you don't use SEO urls at all, you need to call com_content and specify the article id:

```
<a href="index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id={article_id_here}">my link to article1</a>
```